# How can I remove the instances from the cap and ends of a path with an array

Tags: modifiers

I have been using this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA462u7iHW4
However, when I set start and end caps in the array modifier ( just a cube ) it looks like this.

[image]

I don't want to have the sphere instances where the cube caps are. How can I deactivate / remove them?

Merging the plane that gets array'ed does this:
[image]

Comment: Hello ! I think this would be trivial with a geometry nodes setup. Have you explored it or do you need to use this specific workflow ? (Older version, etc)

Comment: @Gorgious I never worked with geometry nodes before, but if it works, I would be happy to learn that solution. Do you know if the specific workflow has a solution as well?

Comment: ok, instead of a plane, just use one vertex, then it works. So select your plane, edit mode -> M -> merge at center should solve your problem

Comment: @chris That ends up removing the spheres as well and the caps still have the spheres. I updated the main post with a second image.

Comment: then pls provide your blend file, so we can check it out. thx

Comment: @Chris I added the blend file to the main post

Answer (score 1):

ok, this isn't possible with array + curve modifier (AFAIK) but with this node setup, you can easily make it with geometry nodes:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time investment and your answer, you are a great help. On which object do I have to bind the node setup on? And do I still need the modifiers, or can I remove them?

Comment: Also, can you please provide the blend file you made? I tried replicating the nodes, but my end result looks very wrong.